# Outlook 2010 message "The rule has a condition that the server cannot process" - how to fix?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, rules

I've just upgraded to Windows 7 & Office 2010 (from XP & Office 2007), and needed to edit a few of my Rules in Outlook. However, when I click OK to close the Rules and Alerts window I get the message "*The rule has a condition that the server cannot process. The action 'stop processing more rules' will prevent all remaining server rules from being carried out. Are you sure this is what you want to do?*"

This would probably be easy for most people, however I have around 50 rules which help me sort server alerts etc into folders, so I don't know which one is "The rule" that the error is referring to. Can anyone help me figure out what the condition is that the "server cannot process"?

Comment: Presumably the rule that has "Stop Processing More Rules" ticked as an action?

Comment: That might cover about 20 of the 50! Any rule where I move the message into a folder needs that checked otherwise a subsequent rule which also matches the message and moves it will actually make a duplicate copy of the message.

Comment: turn on diagnostic logging .. http://www.windvis.com/blog/?p=223

Comment: Thanks, @JeremyW, I've done that, but that article has no info on where the log is! I guess I should google it...

Comment: Ok, so the log has about 20 of these errors after I replicate the problem: 2012/03/30|11:05:09:844|Doc Not Found|4|32400|||||||||0x8004010f|FAIL

Comment: didn't you say that about 20 of your 50 rules have 'stop processing' directives? Coincidence?

Comment: Fair point. I could check the numbers and see, but it doesn't necessarily help solve the issue.

Comment: I think it does and I think it points toward a corrupt rules base. Back up your rules (http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/outlook-2010-tips-backup-export-email-rules/) and then clean them (http://kb.iu.edu/data/apbb.html) and re-import.